# Deleting a file from folder using PHP

Tags: php, file, storage

I am trying to implement a way for user to delete files.  I am using the code below but it doesn't delete the files.  This file is under the root and i checked and made sure that it has permissions to allow users to do what they want, so i am thinking its the script:

```
   $sql = "select `File` from `documents` where `user_id` = '$userid'
   and `doid` = '$doid'";
  $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$fn = $row['File'];

  }
   mysql_free_result($query);

    unlink(/userstash/$fn);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unlink($file) is the correct function to delete a file.

Check if the $fn is filled. And try to use.

```
unlink('/userstash/' . $fn);
```

Comment: Yup.  It says i have to wait a few mins before i can select it.